# Symfony 2 Bizarre behavior in the controller

Tags: symfony, controller

Symfony 2.3
I have two fields on the form with dates: the date_from and date_to.
The controller after submit performs its own validation. After automatic validatin is OK make my own validation of dates. Before adding the code below the form and submit displays after validation:
date_from 2015-10-01 and date_to 2015-10-02
and after adding the code form displays before submit:
date_from 2015-10-01 and date_to 2015-10-02
after submit:
date_from 2015-10-02 and date_to 2015-10-01
Dates are switched. So it writes to the database.

```
    $date_from = $entity->getDatefrom();
$date_to = $entity->getDateto();
$workdays = 0;
for ( $i = $date_from; $i <= $date_to; $i->setTimestamp(strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') . " +1 day") )  )
{
    if ( !in_array($i, $freedays))
    {
        if ( date('N', strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') ) ) < 6 )
        {
            $workdays++ ;
        } 
    }
}
```

When i remove this code dates are not switched. But ofcourse i don't have count of working days.

Comment: If everything is okay after removing the code then just keep it removed.

Comment: :) but i need effect of executing this code. this code does what i want in correct way (it count working days between date_from and date_to). But this code influence other thigs in way which i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference the DateTime Object $date_from using clone before assigning it to $i.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

```
$date_from = $entity->getDatefrom();
$date_to = $entity->getDateto();
$workdays = 0;
for ( $i = clone $date_from; $i <= $date_to; $i->setTimestamp(strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') . " +1 day") )  )
{
    if ( !in_array($i, $freedays))
    {
        if ( date('N', strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') ) ) < 6 )
        {
            $workdays++ ;
        } 
    }
}
```

PHP doesn't copy objects when assigning them to a new variable it just creates a reference.

```
$i = $date_from
```

In this for loop it updates the $i for each iteration

```
$i->setTimestamp(strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') . " +1 day") )
```

Because it's only a reference its this same as

```
$date_from->setTimestamp(strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') . " +1 day") )
// OR even
$entity->getDatefrom()->setTimestamp(strtotime($i->format('Y-m-d') . " +1 day") )
```

Using clone make a copy of the original so `$i->setTimestamp(...)` won't actually apply to `$date_from`

Comment: thx Jason Hendry. I don't understand why but your solution help. Ofcourse i undertand that clone protect $date_from but why it protect from switching $date_to :)

Comment: Thx very. It's clear to me. The reason why `date_from` has new value without cloning You show me and i've update code. Maybe in my question i wrote not so clear that value of `date_to` have got starting value of `date_from` (in case when i've not use clonining) - and that's is what i don't understand.